# Moderately large rate of change yields negative state

Tags: r, desolve

I'm working on Susceptible-Infected-Recovered model, that is defined on a meta-population, and relates cells pairwise through a distance-based scoring. While doing that, my state goes below zero, (S). And I don't understand why.

Turns out that this can happen because somehow there is no "constrain" on the change. Is this me or is there a solution for this?

I've tried to create a smaller, more direct example. This one uses random values, but
it is just to show that the rate is fine when it is relatively small, but then if it changes,
due to many nearby cells being infected (here due to random number), then the estimation fails.

```r
library(deSolve)
ode(
  y = c(
    S1 = 10,
    I1 = 0.001),
  times = 0:5000,
  parms = list(# beta = 0.05
    beta = 0.01),
  func = function(times, state, parms) {
    with(parms, {
      # S <- state[c(1, 3)]
      # I <- state[c(2, 4)]
      S <- state[1]
      I <- state[2]

      beta <- beta + 2 * rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 0.4)

      list(c(dS = -beta * S * I,
             dI = beta * S * I))
    })
  },

  jacfunc = function(t, y, p) {
    with(p, {
      S <- y[1]
      I <- y[2]
      (matrix(
        c(beta * I, beta * S, -beta * I, -beta * S),
        nrow = 2,
        ncol = 2,
        byrow = TRUE
      ))
    })
  },
  jactype = "fullusr",
  verbose = TRUE
) %>%
  # diagnostics() %>%
  print() %>%
  # zapsmall()
  identity()
```

- Specifying `hmin` does nothing to salvage this
- I've also tried providing a jacobian, but this doesn't help anything either.

Comment: The model function must not contain random elements like `rbinom`. Never! Otherwise the solver cannot work properly, as the integration time step is automatically defined by the solver. Instead, just provide a signal with the random parameter  externally via the **forcing** mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! This answers an entirely different question. But that is a question I had five seconds after writing this. I'll look up the forcing mechanism.

Comment: My comment answered exactly your problem and not "a different question". The `rbinom` is the reason why the integration fails. Do the following: Set `verbose = FALSE` and you see the warnings about numerical problems of lsoda. For a better understanding, it could be wise to consult a book about numerical ode solvers.

Comment: The random component is a conceptual error that needs to be fixed first. The original question about "moderately large changes" can be answered differently. One answer is that a `beta=2` should be avoided as it is unrealistically large. Another answer is to run only the interesting part with a smaller time step. The option is `hmax` and not `hmin`. I edited my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Diagnosis

The code contained two issues:

1. The model function needs to be strictly deterministic and must not contain random components, because the solvers cannot converge otherwise. In an ode system, time is continuous by definition, so a random component internally does not make sense. Technically, a solver will then draw different random values for each iteration step, so the model is essentially undefined. If the intention is to provide a variable parameter `beta` it has to be defined beforehand with well-defined time steps.
2. The code line `beta + 2 * rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 0.4)` leads to a value of `beta` switching between 0.01 and 2.01. For this type of model a rate of 2.01 is unrealistically large, not only "moderately". Technically, it runs through and gives a plausible figure with `S` immediately dropping down to zero. However, as the solvers have a limited precision, it can reach (small) negative values..

To get a plausible figure, one can multiply `beta` directly with `beta_t` or multiply only the random part with a value << 2.

### Solution

#### Implement the random component as a forcing

Store the **random component** in an input vector (e.g. `beta_r`) with the same length as `times`. The `time` argument in the model function contains always the current time of the simulation. It is intended to access time varying inputs. Because vectors in **R** start with index 1, use `floor(time) + 1`. The input vector (often called forcing), can be passed to `func` as a global variable or as an additional named argument.

To simplify the example, I omitted the Jacobian.

```r
library(deSolve)

func <- function(time, state, parms, beta_r) {
  with(parms, {
    S <- state[1]
    I <- state[2]

    #beta <- beta + 2 * beta_r[floor(time) + 1]
    beta <- beta * 2 * beta_r[floor(time) + 1]

    list(c(dS = - beta * S * I,
           dI =   beta * S * I))
  })
}

y     <- c(S = 10, I = 0.001)
times <- 0:500
parms <- list(beta = 0.01)
beta_r <- rbinom(length(times), size = 1, prob = 0.4)

## one simulation
out <- ode(y, times, func, parms, beta_r = beta_r)
plot(out)
```

#### A series of simulations

To run a series of simulations, one can use a loop or `lapply`. The `deSolve::plot`-function allows to plot such a list directly.  A pipelined approach is also possible.

```
## a function that runs the model with a new random number series
run_with_new_beta <- function() {
  beta_r <- rbinom(length(times), size = 1, prob = 0.4)
  ode(y, times, func, parms, beta_r = beta_r)
}

## run and plot 10 replicates
out_L <- lapply(1:10, \(.) run_with_new_beta())
plot(out, out_L)
```

[image: 10 stochastic runs]

#### Tune solver parameters for large gradients

As said earlier, `beta = 2.0` is very large for such a system. However, if this is really intended, the time steps can be decreased, either externally with `times` or internally with `hmax`. It is then of course getting very slow.

```r
func <- function(time, state, parms) {
  with(parms, {
    S <- state[1]
    I <- state[2]

    list(c(dS = - beta * S * I,
           dI =   beta * S * I))
  })
}

y     <- c(S = 10, I = 0.001)
times <- 
parms <- list(beta = 2)

## run the interesting short period at the beginning with a small time step
out <- ode(y, times = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100), func, parms)
plot(out)
dplyr::last(out)

## run a longer persiod with a very small internal time step (hmax)
out <- ode(y, times = seq(0, 100), func, parms, hmax=0.001)
summary(out)
```

[image: Simulation with small time step]

Comment: This is very, very help. I did fix the original issue, because the math I was using was wrong. And now I know this for the next bit I have to do. I'm very thankful for this..